# Is it possible to gather the image matrix of a pygame gameboard without rendering the image to the screen?

Tags: image-processing, pygame, rendering, screenshot

I wrote a 2d simulation (very similar to the Atari- OpenAi games) in pygame, which I need for an reinforcement learning project. I'd like to train a neural network using mainly image data, i.e. screenshots of the pygame gameboard.

I am able to make those screenshots, but: 
 - Is possible to gather this image data - or, more precisely, the 
   corresponding rgb image matrix - also without rendering the whole
   playing ground to the screen?

As I figured out there is the possibility to do such in pyglet ... But I would like to avoid to rewrite the whole simulation.

Comment: Hey Florian, I don't see a question mark anywhere in your problem, and its not very specific. Could you please edit it so you are asking a specific question?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I slightly reformulated my post ...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. You don't have to actually draw anything to the screen surface.

Once you have a `Surface`, you can use methods like [`get_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at), the [`PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) module or the [`surfarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module to access the RGB(A)-values of each pixel.

Comment: Thank you for hint! I'm going to see if this works out for me!

Comment: Unfortunately the method get_at() allows to access only one pixel per call - no vectorised access as far as I know! But calling pygame.surfarray.pixels2d() does exactly that what I'm searching for! Thank you!=)